# What's the magic of JavaScript multiply by 1?

Tags: javascript

I've encountered this code:

```js
const currency = "TWD";

function priceMathCeil(_int) {
  if (currency === "TWD") {
    return _int * 1;
  } else {
    return _int;
  }
}
```

I know this code looks useless, but JavaScript has so many **pitfalls** like `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000000000000004` something like that.

So I was wondering if I'm missing anything about multiply by 1 in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a pitfall... that's how computers work.  Look into [floating point math](https://0.30000000000000004.com/).

As for the `* 1`, I suspect it's leftover from a previous currency rate change.  The only other thing would be forcing the type by using this operator, but I can't see why someone would do that only in the case of a certain currency.